# Consultar varias tablas para obtener valores no iguales

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo con una consulta que estoy queriendo hacer.

tengo las siguientes tres tablas

```html
roles_modulos          modulos                roles
modulo_id | role_id   id | nombre            id | nombre
-------------------   -----------             -----------
        1 | 2          1 | Administracion     1 | ROLE_SECURITY
        2 | 1          2 | Reportes           2 | ROLE_ACCESS
        2 | 2          3 | Usuarios           3 | ROLE_ADMIN
        2 | 4          4 | Roles              4 | ROLE_DEFAULT
        2 | 5                                 5 | ROLE_USER
        3 | 4
        4 | 5
```

roles_modulos: es la relacion de M:M de Roles y Módulos en este caso la uso para asignarle módulos a los roles y que los roles tengan modulos asignados.

El punto es que quiero traer en una o varias consultas que módulos están asignados a un rol.

Hice un left join mostrando los modulos que tienen asignado un rol.

```
select Estado='True', M.nombre as 'Modulo', RM.modulo_id, R.nombre as 'Rol', RM.role_id from 
roles_modulos as RM
left join modulos as M ON M.id = RM.modulo_id
left join roles as R ON RM.role_id = R.id where RM.role_id=5
```

Esta consulta trae los módulos que tiene asignado un rol en este caso el rol 5

```
| Estado | Modulo  | modulo_id | Rol                 | role_id |
|:-------|:-------:| ---------:| ------:------------:|-------: |
| True   | Reportes|  3        | ROLE_SECURITY       | 5       |
| True   | Roles   |  4        | ROLE_SECURITY       | 5       |
```

Ahora estoy intentando traer los módulos que no están asignados al rol intente replicar la primera consulta que trae los módulos que si están asignados a un rol solo le puse no equals en `M ON M.id <> RM.modulo_id` para mostrar los módulos que no estén asignados al rol que se busco.

```
select Estado='False', M.nombre as 'Modulo', RM.modulo_id, R.nombre as 'Rol', RM.role_id from 
    roles_modulos as RM
    left join modulos as M ON M.id <> RM.modulo_id
    left join roles as R ON RM.role_id = R.id where RM.role_id=5
```

esta consulta me trae todos los modulos que tiene, que no tiene y repetidos, entonces mi duda si esta bien esa consulta o se puede hacer de otra forma mejor o que forma es la correcta???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías arrancar pidiendo todos los `modulos` y luego ver si el rol lo tiene asignado o no.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    IIF(RM.modulo_id IS NULL, 'False', 'True') AS 'Estado',
    M.nombre AS 'Modulo',
    M.id AS 'modulo_id',
    R.nombre AS 'Rol',
    RM.role_id
FROM modulos AS M
    LEFT JOIN roles_modulos AS RM 
        ON RM.modulo_id = M.id
        AND RM.role_id = 5
    LEFT JOIN roles AS R 
        ON RM.role_id = R.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29f4051fe808821596877e40ff5a62c1)</kbd>

Comment: Me da un error de an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected cuando ejecuto la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es generar todas las opciones posibles mediante un `CROSS JOIN` y luego eliminar las opciones existentes.

```
DECLARE @Rol_ID int = 5;

SELECT 'False'    AS Estado, 
       M.nombre   AS Modulo, 
       M.id       AS modulo_id, 
       R.nombre   AS Rol, 
       R.id       AS role_id 
FROM Modulos AS M
CROSS JOIN Roles AS R
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT *  
                  FROM roles_modulos as RM
                  WHERE M.id = RM.modulo_id
                  AND   R.id = RM.role_id)
AND R.id = @Rol_ID;
```